# Prove $f\in L_2$ if $\langle f,g\rangle< C\|g\|_{L_2}$ for any $g\in D$ and $\overline{D}=L_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $D$ be a subset of and dense in $L_2$. If $\langle f,g\rangle<C\|g\|_{L_2}$ for a constant $C$ and any $g\in D$, then $f$ must be in $L_2$.

I read this statement in a paper. I think it is right, because the following argument makes sense. The fact that $\langle f,g\rangle< C\|g\|_{L_2}$ for any $g\in D$ implies that $f$ is a linear functional on $L_2$. It is known that the dual of $L_2$ is $L_2$. Thus $f$ should be in $L_2$. This argument is not rigorous and I think the **duality of $L_2$** is a bit too advanced for this statement. Could anyone give a tip of an **elementary proof** that does not require the duality property?

If needed, $D$ is the set of compact support functions in $C^{\infty}$ and $\langle f,g\rangle=\int f\bar{g}$. We can consider the problem in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$. But I guess that what $D$ is exactly does not matter, except that it is dense in $L_2$.

Comment: What do you know about $f$? How do you define $\langle f, g\rangle$?

Comment: What is $D$, and on what space are you taking $L^2$?

Comment: @gerw $\langle f,g\rangle=\int f\bar{g}$ as usual. $D$ is compact support functions in $C^{\infty}$. But I guess what $\overline{D}$ is exactly does not matter. The density property plays the role. Am I right ?

Comment: @TrialAndError  $D$ is compact support functions in $C^{\infty}$. We can consider it in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$. But I guess the space does not matter.

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted to this question of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481033/if-f-in-c0-1-int-01f2tdt-infty-can-one-construct-g-in-c0 . I think the solution could be adapted to give an elementary proof of what you want to show. Start by assuming $\int f^2dx =\infty$ and $f$ is real, and see if Kelenner's solution will work.

Comment: I don't think this is true, for if $f(x) = 1$ is constant and $g \in D$, then $\langle f,g \rangle = \int \bar g$ is finite since $g$ is compactly supported and continuous. But obviously $f \notin L_2$.

Comment: Also, $f$ gives you a linear functional on $D$ yes, but it may not be bounded, so it may not extend to an element of $L_2^*$. But I believe the statement is true if the hypothesis is strengthened to $|\langle f,g \rangle| < C \|g\|_2$ for any $g \in D$.

Comment: @arkeet Yes, you are right. It should be $|\langle f,g\rangle|<C\|g\|_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the result is not true as stated. For a different counterexample, take $f \in L^1(0,1) \setminus L^2(0,1)$ and $D = L^\infty(0,1)$.

However, it is true if you require additionally $\langle f, g\rangle \le C \|g\|_{L^2}$. Then, $f$ is continuous on $(D,\|\cdot\|_{L^2})$ and can be extended uniquely to a functional on $L^2$ by density of $D$. Hence, there is $F \in L^2$ with $\langle f, g\rangle = \langle F, g\rangle$ for all $g \in D$. Now, you can use the density of $D$ again to get $f = F$.

Comment: Actually the last two sentences beginning with "Hence" are equivalent to the application of Riesz representation theorem. Right?

Comment: @Hua Yes, the existence of $F \in L^2$ is an application of Riesz' theorem.

Comment: This argument still appeals to duality of $L_2$. I guess the **elementary** proof is not that easy to come up. Then I accept it as answer.